# Foundry dataset columns and properties in multiple language

Tags: palantir-foundry

Is there in PLTR Foundry an option to have dataset column names or Object types properties names presented in different languages, as opposed to the current English format. SAP has a functionality, where the language display is automatically adjusted based on the user's login language.

Comment: this is in control of your Foundry admin team. 
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/administration/configure-languages/